# Why is the standard inner product on F^n equal to this?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

In the textbook that I'm using the standard inner product is defined as

$$\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\overline{b_{i}}$$

where $x=(a_{1}, a_{2}, {...}, a_{n})$ and $y=(b_{1}, b_{2}, {...}, b_{n})$ and the bar denotes complex conjugation.

In one the practice problems I was doing they used the fact that

$\langle x,y\rangle = y^{*}x$

where $y^{*}$ denotes the conjugate transpose of y. I'm having trouble understanding why the definition for the standard inner product is the same as $y^{*}x$.

I tried doing an example where $x = (i,i)$ and $y = (-i,-i)$

For $$\langle x,y\rangle = i*i+i*i=-2$$

On the other hand

$y^{*}x=\begin{pmatrix} i\\i\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} i & i\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1\\ -1 & -1\\ \end{pmatrix} $

I was wondering why I am getting $\langle x,y\rangle \ne y^{*}x$

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are **column vectors**, not row vectors. Consider this and recalculate.

Comment: When we write ${\bf y}* {\bf x}$, we're interpreting ${\bf x}, {\bf y}$ as *column* vectors. In particular, ${\bf y}^*$ is a row vector, so ${\bf y}^* {\bf x}$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, which we can identify the its sole entry.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for making x and y column vectors or is it just convention?

Comment: Otherwise the mnemonic "**co**ordinates always **co**lumns" would fail. :-)

Comment: We use column vectors because of the convention that coefficients are written to the left of the variable. With column vectors, we can put the matrix to the left of the vector. With row vectors, the matrix has to be on the right.